# Bitsrc: Error: Unknown object type "window" when tagging a component

Tags: bit, bit-src

I get the mentioned error when I try to tag a component and I don't know how to diagnose the problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you please provide additional information like which compiler did you used, it's version etc?

Comment: If you can provide a mini example which makes the error happen or which files you are adding